# Flutter GetX: pass data from GetVuew constructor to GetController and use data in async onInit

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to find a solution to pass data from GetView constructor to GetController and then use the data in the onInit function in GetController.

I have the following code in GetController

```
class ListItemController extends GetController {
    int id = 0;

    @override
    public Future<void> onInit() async {
        List<Item> items = await ListItem(id);
    }
}
```

and I have the GetView as

```
public ListItemView extends GetView<ListItemController> {
    ListItemView({
        super.key,
        int id,
    }) {
        controller.id = id;
    }
}
```

I can see in `ListItemView`, id has a correct value and `controller.id = id;` does not throw any exception. However, in the onInit in `ListItemController`, `id` value is still 0.

What could be wrong or what is the best way to pass data? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it was to use `GetParameters`:

First, in the route you can do:

```
GetPage(name: '/listItemView/:id', page: () => ListItemView()),
```

Then in the controller:

```
class ListItemController extends GetController {
    int id = Get.parameters['id']!;

    @override
    public Future<void> onInit() async {
        List<Item> items = await ListItem(id);
    }
}
```

And the view would be:

```
public ListItemView extends GetView<ListItemController> {
    ListItemView({super.key});
}
```